# Why is my segue crashing on overridden sendEvent?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In VC1, a button has a triggered segue action to VC2. When I tap on the button in VC1, the app crashes on an override of sendEvent as I try to call the super.

```
public class UIApplicationSub: UIApplication {
    // properties here

    override public func sendEvent(event: UIEvent) {
            super.sendEvent(event)
            // reset idle timer here
```

I'm not certain, but from the crash report below it looks like I'm getting a keyValueCoding error when VC2 is loading, however the new view is just some buttons and there are no outlets set on them.

Any ideas on what may be causing this crash?

```
Incident Identifier: 35C240D4-60EF-41E9-B2F4-9A288806EFEF
CrashReporter Key:   81571a82664994674b5d12cbd33bb0c911f5c23f
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Version:             2.14 (8.00)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-01-20 08:53:57.57 -0500
Launch Time:         2016-01-20 08:53:41.41 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18186d900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x180edbf80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18186d5c0 -[NSException raise] + 12
3   Foundation                      0x182167f74 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 268
4   UIKit                           0x1868cff1c -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 104
5   UIKit                           0x186c187cc -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection performConnect] + 908
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1817973ac -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 232
7   UIKit                           0x186a296a0 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1748
8   UIKit                           0x1868d333c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 376
9   UIKit                           0x18669c250 -[UIViewController loadView] + 176
10  UIKit                           0x18655fd6c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 144
11  UIKit                           0x18655fcc4 -[UIViewController view] + 28
12  UIKit                           0x186e2aca0 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 92
13  UIKit                           0x1868b70dc -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 136
14  UIKit                           0x1868dcc24 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3780
15  UIKit                           0x1868df9c0 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 472
16  UIKit                           0x186659cec -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 184
17  UIKit                           0x186c847e4 __74-[UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 144
18  UIKit                           0x186c8b63c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 456
19  UIKit                           0x186c8b440 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 92
20  UIKit                           0x186c8b708 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 160
21  UIKit                           0x186597e50 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100
22  UIKit                           0x186597dcc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
23  UIKit                           0x18657fa88 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 416
24  UIKit                           0x1865976e4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572
25  UIKit                           0x186597314 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 804
26  UIKit                           0x18658fe30 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 784
27  UIKit                           0x1865604cc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248
28  DigitalLife                     0x100899420 UIApplicationSub.sendEvent(UIEvent) -> () (UIApplicationSub.swift:50)
29  DigitalLife                     0x10089999c @objc UIApplicationSub.sendEvent(UIEvent) -> () (UIApplicationSub.swift:0)
30  UIKit                           0x18655e794 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5528
31  CoreFoundation                  0x181824efc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
32  CoreFoundation                  0x181824990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
33  CoreFoundation                  0x181822690 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
34  CoreFoundation                  0x181751680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
35  GraphicsServices                0x182c60088 GSEventRunModal + 180
36  UIKit                           0x1865c8d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
37  DigitalLife                     0x10031f334 main (main.swift:11)
38  libdyld.dylib                   0x1812f28b8 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181410140 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001814d8ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181381dac abort + 140
3   DigitalLife                     0x000000010095fce8 -[PLCrashReporter generateLiveReportWithThread:] + 0
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018186dc88 __handleUncaughtException + 652
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180edc23c _objc_terminate() + 112
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180ecef44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180eceb10 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180edc120 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181751728 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000182c60088 GSEventRunModal + 180
11  UIKit                           0x00000001865c8d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
12  DigitalLife                     0x000000010031f334 main (main.swift:11)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001812f28b8 start + 4
```

Comment: what kind of event did you want to send to VC2 ? did you want to move to other VC programmatically ?

Comment: Hi Aaron. Can you click on the button that is triggering the issue and in Xcode inspector, check the connections. What does it show the button connected to?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you click on the button causing the issue and in Xcode, click the Connection inspector. See what the button is connected to.

Similar issues may be caused by copying a view controller and reusing it in the storyboard. Sometimes the connections to other outlets is copied too and at run time it causes issues.

If the thought is right, make sure to delete the IBAction and write a new one and connect it to the button.

Comment: To add to this -- it's likely the issue you're seeing is coming from VC2, not VC1. There are likely lingering bad outlets in the storyboard.

Comment: The problem was definitely in VC2. A button there was connected to a nonexistent outlet. I'm guessing I didn't get the not keyValue compliant because I had overridden sendEvent.